# Parsing JPEG bytestream markers with regex

Tags: python, arrays, regex, parsing, jpeg

I am working on writing a python program to manipulate information in a JPEG image. I am however having trouble getting my regular expression to look for the byte marker codes used in JPEG images.

For example: the start of image marker is `\xFF\xD8` and the end of image marker is `\xFF\xD9`. The pattern I tried using was: `rb'\xFF\xD8(.+?)\xFF\xD9'`. No success there. What should my pattern be if I want to find everything in between specific byte markers in a byte array?

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes with another backslash

Comment: `.` in a regex does not match newline characters by default - and a JPEG file is almost certainly going to contain some newlines just by accident.  Pass `re.DOTALL` as the flags parameter (available on almost all regex methods) to make `.` match any byte.

Comment: Thank you. I actually was aware of this. My actual code that finds the matches is as follows. `matches = re.findall(pattern, data, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'r' prefix on a string says "ignore backslash escapes" so it's ignoring them.

This means you are looking for a string with the first four characters literally r'\', 'x', 'F', and 'F'

Remove the r and double any backslashes that are part of the regular expression rather than escapes to represent binary characters.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would it be better to remove the r or add another backslash in front of each byte?

Comment: Remove the r and double any backslashes that are part of the regular expression rather than escapes to represent binary characters.  I'll edit the answer to say this so the answer will be complete.

Comment: The `r` prefix does mean that backslashes aren't interpreted as escapes by Python's string literal syntax - but that just means that they are available to be interpreted by the regex compiler (and `\x` for hexadecimal values is one that the regex compiler does implement).  You almost always want to use the `r` prefix with regular expressions.